# Wicket : throw new RestartResponseException to logout and redirect

Tags: java, session, wicket, logout

I have a problem to redirect a page after invalidating session using Wicket.

Careers1 is a page, that needs user to be logged in, with six buttons linked to other pages and an a href button, which get the user logged out.
My code apparently works, because if I click to log out, and I click to one of the six buttons, it redirects me to the log in page.
But I need it to redirect me immediately, after I clicked "log out".

I tried setResponsePage() and also adding signOut() the problem is the same of the RestartResponseException.

Here is my code

Careers1:

```
public class Careers1 extends WebPage
{
   public Careers1()
   {
      Link logoutLink = new Link("logout") 
      {
        @Override
        public void onClick()
        {
          getSession().invalidate();
          throw new RestartResponseException(Careers1.class);   
        }
      };

      add(logoutLink);
   } 
}
```

On careers.html I have

```
<div class="logout" > <a wicket:id="logout" href="#"> LOG OUT </a></div>
```

Which should invalidate the session, and redirect the user to the login.

Comment: Why are you not redirecting simply with setResponsePage()?

Comment: Because it doesn't work... :(

Comment: You mean with "it doens't work" that the code gets executed but you are not redirected? Because in a recent project I used it as suggested and it works fine:
Link logoutLink = new Link("logoutLink")
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick()
            {
                MySession.get().signOut();
                MySession.get().invalidate();
setResponsePage(WicketApplication.get().getHomePage());
            }
        };

Comment: it doesn't work just in the same way the exception doesn't work: I'm not redirected.
Also tried signOut... same problem.

Comment: Hm... I overlooked that you are redirecting to the same page (Careers1). The invalidate() invalidates the session at the end of the current request. Try to redirect directly to the login-page or try to use invalidateNow() which invalidates the session immediately.

Comment: @JoachimRohde Rohde On the one hand redirecting explicitly to the login page is not always an option and in general is not the same thing, because in that case continueToOriginalDestination() would not know where to go after successful authentication. The OP clearly needs the login to lead the user back to the current page after successful authentication, whatever the current page was. On the other hand I've tried invalidateNow() myself in a sample project and it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @LucioCrusca But we are talking here about logging out. As far as I understood the OP the problem is that after logging out no redirect is happening, even though the session is invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try forcing wicket to redirect immediately using a fake page that just redirects back to Careers1. Let's name it RedirectorPage:

```
public class RedirectorPage extends WebPage
{
  @Override
  protected void onBeforeRender()
  {
    throw new RestartResponseException(Careers1.class);
  }
}
```

Now in the logout link of Careers1 you redirect to RedirectorPage. That worked for me, but only after I moved the exception of RedirectorPage into onBeforeRender(). Throwing the exception in the page constructor still makes wicket ignore the fact the session has already been invalidated.